# Why does the price of a crypto currency change while swapping on a dex?

Tags: uniswap, pancakeswap, defi

I have been looking for an answer to this question for a while but haven't found a reasonable explanation yet.

While attempting to swap ***ETH*** for ***USDT*** on *quickswap* , I noticed that I would need ***3496.1 USDT*** to buy ***1 ETH***.

However when I click on the swap arrow , it shows that if I were to swap back the ***1* ETH** I'd get back only ***3471.24 USDT*** thus losing ***25 USDT*** almost instantly. [image]

What causes this price discrepancy?

Comment: It's called price impact and is caused by the changes in the pool's asset composition due to your trade, as well as the trading fees.

Answer (score 1):

You are paying 0.30% fee to liquidity providers.

This will change the outcome either buy or sell way.